# Is there a "load from Outlook attachment" pipeline for Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Looking for information on how to load data received over email (attached as `.xslx` or `.csv`), and load them into data storage with Azure Data Factory.

I've been unable to search for a solution --- all I can find with keywords "Data Factory" and "email" will direct me to questions like "how to set up email notifications for data factory."

Any pointers on which pipeline module to use or any related articles are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: hi,if my answer helps you, would you please accept it as an answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually,ADF copy activity supports [office 365 connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-office-365#approving-new-data-access-requests).

[image]

You could follow above link to create linkedService and DateSet.

[image]

When you create Linkedservice,you need to grant Mail Read permission to sp id and secret.

[image]

In dataset,you could define below properties in the structure json.

[image]

Then you could set blob storage as sink dataset of copy activity which i think you already know.