# Azure - Download attachment's from Outlook without using logicapp and move it to Blob Storage

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-data-factory, azure-runbook

Can we download the file or attachment from outlook using azure and move it to blobstorage.

Regards
Richard

List item

Comment: Sure, it is a matter of writing some code. Azure itself is a broad range of services, pick one and have a go, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Office365 connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-office-365). Then use Office365 as source and Blob Storage as sink.

You can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-office-365-data) and this question [Is there a "load from Outlook attachment" pipeline for Azure Data Factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60536173/is-there-a-load-from-outlook-attachment-pipeline-for-azure-data-factory).